# CoreOS/etcd cluster minimum hosts

Tags: docker, cluster-computing, coreos, etcd

I'm evaluating a strategy for implementing docker for a small company with 2 servers. We wanted to have them both working as a cluster, to load balance the work, but to work as a fail-safe for one another in case of failure.

From what I understand, etcd requires a minimum of 3 up hosts or you lose the ability to put/get keys. That would not be possible with 2 machines, and with 3 machines none could fail. Is this assessment correct?

The only solution would be to have a single etcd but that would mean that if the machine that failed was the "etcd"-one then both would stop working correctly...

Just to clarify, I wanted the benefits of something like fleetd's scheduling and clustering abilities but with a small sized deploy. Moving containers/systemd-units and data manually between hosts is my backup plan, but less than ideal.

Comment: https://coreos.com/docs/cluster-management/scaling/etcd-optimal-cluster-size/

Answer (score 0):

You can run coreos with only 2 hosts, however you will lose your etcd cluster once you don't have a quorum, with only 2 machines this is possible if both are rebooted. With 3 hosts, you have a much higher likelihood of having a quorum if all machines are rebooted.

If you are willing to have one always be considered master, you can do this, you just have to be sure that you understand how to make an etcd peer consider itself master if quorum is lost.

If you have static IP's, then you have more control over your cluster and should be fine with setting the cluster IP's then even if both servers are restarted, they should be able to discover each other and reach a stable state.

Take a looks at the [docs](https://github.com/coreos/etcd/blob/master/Documentation/clustering.md)